# Stream music via bluetooth "phone call"

Tags: ios, bluetooth, a2dp

My car radio doesn't support A2DP.
Then I realized that Google Maps plays the navigation sounds over the "phone call protocol". It's like Google Maps is calling me. :D

Is there a app or something like that to do that with the Music Apps of iOS (e.g. Spotify)?

Thank you for answers!

Comment: Is that related to programming?

Comment: If you can tell me, how to program that, yes. Than I will do it. But if there is an existing alternative, it is not needed.